# Rewriting URL with htaccess

Tags: html, wordpress, .htaccess

I am trying to rewrite the url to my wordpress theme folder as so:

Actual URL: `http://www.mydomain.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme/style.css`

Trying to rewrite to: `http://www.mydomain.com/mytheme/style.css`

Here is what I have in my .htaccess file which is in my home folder, and is not working:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^mytheme/(.*) /wp-content/themes/mytheme/$1 [QSA,L]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#Begin WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^mytheme/(.*) /wp-content/themes/mytheme/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^plugins/(.*) /wp-content/plugins/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
#End WordPress
```

This is how your htaccess should look like.

But you need to tell wordpress to use the new Urls.

I recommend that you check out this github repo [Roots Boilerplate->lib](https://github.com/roots/roots/tree/master/lib)

Especially files rewrites and relative urls.

Answer (score 0):

Is that the only line that you have in your .htaccess file?

You need to have `RewriteEngine On` above that line in order for the RewriteRules to work.

Comment: Sorry, I do have that as well. Updated above. Thanks.